# Deploying Silverlight Application on IIS7

Tags: silverlight, iis-7

We have a silverlight application written in Visual Studio (VS) 2010 and we want to deploy it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box (IIS7). To deploy it in VS I did a right click on the MyProject.Web project, selected "Publish...", from the "Publish method" I selected "File System". I copied the folder over to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" on the server. In IIS Manager I did a right click on the folder, selected "Convert to Application", a window popped up, where you can select the application pool. I selected the default (.NET 4), I clicked on "Test Settings..." it failed (that was a bad sign), clicked ok.
When I try to access the website from a browser a message box pops up saying do you want to open or save "MySilverlightApp"?
Basically, it wants to download the xap file like it would download a text file or a doc file, it doesn't "run" it.
I have checked the forums and most cases the issue is that the MIME file types are not set up, but I have checked that it's all looks good, and it should as well because on IIS7 it's all set up by default so I am puzzled a bit here.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, what exactly are you interested? I have two projects in the solution. The first one (FelixApps) holds the silverlight application. It has 8 xaml files and 8 corresponding cs files. In the second project (FelixProj.web) we have the web services and the web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route cause of the issue was that the XAP file (inside the ClientBin folder) was the default document.
When I set the aspx file (in the application root folder) as the default document, it started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized that you tried something about mime types so I need to edit my answer. I want to share a link to provide you a guide. It may be helpful to see if you miss a point.

http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications